# Origin of "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006" in golang

Tags: time, go

In golang [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants), it is stated that :

> These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse.
>   The reference time used in the layouts is:
>
> `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445

What is the origin of this specific date ?

Comment: 15:04:05 is just after 3PM ... 1 2 3 4 5 6 ?

Comment: This date contains no ambigous fields. If I write 2/2006.1, 4/3.5 it's entirely clear which number belongs to which part of the date.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

That's explained immediately after the section you quoted:

> Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as
>
> `01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700`

It's a simple increasing sequence: 01 02 03 04 05 (PM) 06 07.

Using 03:04 **PM** rather than 03:04 **AM** makes it possible to show the two time representations `15:04` and `03:04PM` more clearly (this is speculation on my part).

Comment: Why didn't they just use `2001-02-03 03:04:05PM -0700` or something like that. :( Would be so much easier to remember than `2nd of January 2006`.

Comment: @AndreKR: Why do you need to remember it?

Comment: @KeithThompson I came here because I had to google it because I had written `time.ParseInLocation("` and that doesn't have the reference date in the inline docs. First world problem, definitely.

Comment: KeithThompson: Because it’s a mnemonic device, and any mnemonic device worth its salt has to be easy to remember. To that end, MDY is sub-par, but MDTY is worse. :-P @AndreKR: My guess is that it’s because it’s the default format used by [date(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html). As for why date(1) is the way it is, I have wondered that myself for years. It’s worth noting it was written in ’Murica during the pre-ISO-8601, pre-RFC-2822 dark ages, and is now a deeply-rooted part of UNIX history. But for the real answer, we’d probably have to ask Ken Thompson.

Answer (score 31):

It is just the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1: month (January, Jan, 01, etc)

2: day

3: hour (15 is 3pm on a 24 hour clock)

4: minute

5: second

6: year (2006)

7: timezone (GMT-7 is MST)