# golang time.Parse error hour out of range same format

Tags: go

i have time in string, which is like this format `31 July 2023 21:06:36`. i want to make time from it by using parse. so i did this

```golang
    dateStr := "20 July 2023 21:06:36"
    formatLayout := "31 July 2023 21:06:36"
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse(formatLayout, dateStr)
    if err != nil {
        return detail, err
    }
```

but it got error `parsing time "31 July 2023 21:06:36": hour out of range`. then i change the format layout to be `02 January 2006 15:04:05`

```golang
    dateStr := "20 July 2023 21:06:36"
    formatLayout := "02 January 2006 15:04:05"
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse(formatLayout, dateStr)
    if err != nil {
        return detail, err
    }
```

it produce the right time. my question is why if use layout of `02 January 2006 15:04:05` it does not produce error but `31 July 2023 21:06:36` produce error. they are at same format right?

thanks

Comment: They are not the same format. The values in the format string determines the fields. 01 is month, 2006 is year, 2 is month, 3 or 15 is hour, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` (or `01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700`) is the value of the [`Layout` constant defined in the `time` package](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants).

It's defined like this because every part of the time (day, month, year, hour, minute, seconds, timezone) is different, so it's convenient to use as a layout, since it does not contain ambiguous fields. E.g. month is always 1, day is always 2, etc.

You can see that as a "special" time that `time` package uses to perform parsing. Nothing really more.

See also [Origin of "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006" in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530327/origin-of-mon-jan-2-150405-mst-2006-in-golang).

Answer (score 0):

`layout` needs to hold the specific date: `"01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700"`, as that's the value of the constant `Layout` in the [time package](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants).

```
const (
    Layout      = "01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700" // The reference time, in numerical order.
    
    ...
)
```

So, the parameter `layout` goal is to tell the parser where each element is located (year, month, day, hour, etc.) in your format. As the parser knows the exact date inside `layout` and because every element in that exact date is different ( `month in 1`, `day is 2`, `hour is 3`, and so on), it can understand your format and discard any value that is not an element.

That allows you things like:

```
    dateStr := "20 July (I love dates) 2023 21:06:36"
    formatLayout := "02 January (I love dates) 2006 15:04:05"
    parsedTime, _ := time.Parse(formatLayout, dateStr)
```

You can try it [here](https://go.dev/play/p/RWGsnnqhI6F).

Check the [doc of the function here](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse).